# Intervention\Image from Laravel doesn't manage webp

Tags: php, laravel, gd, laravel-5.5, intervention

On my development server everything works great, the images I upload via a form are converted with

```
Image::make($img)->encode('webp');
```

and when I go to check it, it's perfect.

On my production server things are a bit different, for example if I upload a square image (completely red), after the encoding I end up with a brownish/gold image and with other images I end up with an empty space.

Since the image is being created, I think there's a problem just with the encoding, maybe some configuration I missed..

> Version of GD library on dev server is 2.4.1 and on production 2.1.1
>
> Everything runs on Ubuntu 17.10 on dev and 16.04 production.
>
> Laravel version 5.5
>
> **EDIT**
>
> PHP version 7.0 on both dev and production
>
> **EDIT 2**
>
> This is the kind of image that comes out
>
> [image: This is the kind of image that comes out]

Comment: I got some problems with GD - have you tried ImageMagick?

Comment: I tried installing imagemagick (compiling it with support to webp) and setting up imagick module, but it says "webp format is not supported by this imagick installation"

Comment: maybe this issue from gdlib will help u: https://github.com/libgd/libgd/issues/254

Comment: Tried bumping up the quality? `Image::make($img)->encode('webp', 100);`

Comment: I tried now to set it to ->encode('webp', 100) with no success. Still the same quality.

Comment: Can you upgrade production to GD 2.4.1, or downgrade dev to 2.1.1 to determine if that's the cause?

Comment: have u tried command line cwebp

Comment: that ways you will know weather its server side error or its bad code

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot update libgd-dev to the latest version because i'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and the only package I can download is 2.1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I might have done something wrong (more experienced people, please correct me) but I got it working.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the only available package for libgd-dev is 2.1.1 so this is what I've done to upgrade it:

downloaded these packages from `https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/{name-of-the-package}/download`

> zlib1g_1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
>
> zlib1g-dev_1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
>
> libwebp6_0.6.0-3_amd64.deb
>
> libpng16-16_1.6.34-1_amd64.deb
>
> libgd3_2.2.5-3_amd64.deb
>
> libgd-dev_2.2.5-3_amd64.deb

I installed them in the order that I listed them in, however I simply saw which dependency dpkg was complaining about and installed it.

The image encoding code now works flawlessly

Comment: Faced with the same problem, but can't find libgd-dev_2.2.5-3_amd64.deb which version can I replace on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS?